# Problem installing gscam

Tags: gscam, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm trying to install the gscam packet for Rovio. I've checked out the package into the directory /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks. When I try to use the command rosmake --rosdep-install gscam I always get this error "mkdir: cannot create directory `build': Permission denied". I've tried to change the permissions of the directory with no results.
What is wrong?
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9478/problem-installing-gscam/) by [Antonio](https://answers.ros.org/users/311/antonio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2011-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do not modify the `/opt/ros` install trees. They contain shared binaries, already built for your system.

To add another package and build it from source, see the [new package downloading](http://answers.ros.org/question/165/for-new-package-downloading) question. In your case, specify `/opt/ros/diamondback` in place of `/opt/ros/cturtle`.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Antonio](https://answers.ros.org/users/311/antonio/) on 2011-03-21**:
Thank you very much, I follow your suggestion and it works. I can't fix the problem using rosmake on the downloaded package, but I'd like to thanks also GeniusGeeko for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This assumes you have "source /opt/ros/diamondback/setup.bash" added to the end of ~/.bashrc

1. > sudo gedit /opt/ros/diamondback/setup.sh
2. Change line

   > export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks

   to

   > export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks:~/ros_packages
3. > mkdir ~/ros_packages && cd ~/ros_packages
4. > svn checkout http://brown-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/experimental/gscam
5. restart terminal
6. > rosmake --rosdep-install gscam

Cheers, Bryce

---

Originally posted by [GeniusGeeko](https://answers.ros.org/users/153/geniusgeeko/) with karma: 299 on 2011-03-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Antonio](https://answers.ros.org/users/311/antonio/) on 2011-03-21**:
But I don't know where's the problem. If I try to compile the stacks alredy present in the diamondback package everything it's ok, the problem it's when I try to add new package from svn. I've checked the enviroment variable and follow the tutorial, but the problem it's still there.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-03-20**:
The permissions problem is a clue that you are going about it wrong.

**Comment by [Antonio](https://answers.ros.org/users/311/antonio/) on 2011-03-20**:
As super user it can't recognize the command rosmake. I've also tried to reinstall all the binaries but I get always the mkdir error...

**Comment by [GeniusGeeko](https://answers.ros.org/users/153/geniusgeeko/) on 2011-03-20**:
Try the top steps after you use, "sudo su"

**Comment by [Antonio](https://answers.ros.org/users/311/antonio/) on 2011-03-20**:
Yes, it's always "mkdir: cannot create directory `build': Permission denied", nothing has changed

**Comment by [GeniusGeeko](https://answers.ros.org/users/153/geniusgeeko/) on 2011-03-20**:
Are you getting the same error?

**Comment by [Antonio](https://answers.ros.org/users/311/antonio/) on 2011-03-20**:
Hi, thank you for your assistance. I follow your suggestion but I still can't solve the problem! Do you have any other suggestion?

**Comment by [GeniusGeeko](https://answers.ros.org/users/153/geniusgeeko/) on 2011-03-18**:
I just love having all of my installed stacks in one neat place. Its just my opinion though.